# Unserialise New Moodle Log Json Format

Tags: json, moodle, u-sql

Hi I wonder anyone can help here.

One of my project involves Moodle where they recently changed from old log format to new log format. The older version was standard json and new version has serialised json look like format. below here are examples of both format.

Old format

```
{"modulename":"assign","instanceid":"3","name":"Assignent_test_two"}
```

New format

```
a:3:{s:10:"modulename";s:6:"assign";s:10:"instanceid";s:1:"3";s:4:"name";s:18:"Assignent_test_two";}
```

How can we convert data from new format to a standard json old format ideally in c# or , SQL or in USQL?

Those attributes in new format are data type and length of the value expected.

Answer (score 0):

you should probably `json_encode(unserialize($data))` but this is for PHP

Comment: Thank you for that. Unfortunately we cannot use PHP, the processing engine has to be either sql,c#,  perl or python based.